# How will the stack of this function will look like?

Tags: javascript, stack

When I do the following:

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {
  function add(number) {
    return number + amount;
  }
  return add;
}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
alert(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

Will each instance of `makeAddFunction` have a separate stack or all of them will use the same stack? and does the order of variables entering and leaving the stack matter?

Comment: There's only one instance of `makeAddFunction`...?? You mean each call to it?

Comment: @sje397 Are those not two different instances? how then can they hold 2 different values of the same variable?

Comment: There are two instances of functions called `add`, returned from calls to a single instance of `makeAddFunction`, and the variables store references to those.

Comment: @sje397 Thanx, so what would be the difference if I wanted to make two instances of `makeAddFunction`? should I only adding `new`?

Comment: You could make two instances of functions called `makeAddFunction` the same way you do for `add` in the code above. Adding `new` would treat `makeAddFunction` as a constructor, where `this` inside the function is a new object of type `makeAddFunction`.

Answer (score 2):

Each function call creates a new `Function` (-Context). So to answer that quickly, yes they will have separate "stacks" in terms of ECMAscripts `Execution Contexts`.

I'm not so sure what you mean with "the order of variables entering and leaving the stack".

ECMAscript is all about contexts (objects). There is a stack of Execution Contexts which get called in order. After one context finished, the parent context continues to run until it's also finished (and so forth). That principle lasts as long as there are any contextes if not, the `Global context` gets the attention again.